# Save list of data in sqflite database flutter

Tags: flutter, api, sqflite

I'm trying to fetch data from API and store them in a sqflite local database.

Here's my code of fetching data from API

```
List _loadedPhotos = [];

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
    final data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      _loadedPhotos = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _loadedPhotos.isEmpty
            ? Center(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: _fetchData,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.get_app),
                ),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _loadedPhotos.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Image.network(
                      _loadedPhotos[index]['thumbnailUrl'],
                      width: 150,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    title: Text(_loadedPhotos[index]['title']),
                    subtitle: Text('Photo ID: ${_loadedPhotos[index]['id']}'),
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So I need to store this list of data in local database.
What is the best way to do?
I referred https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite
But how do I insert this list of data to db?
I appreciate your help on this.
Thank you!

Comment: convert each item in the list to a row and then use an insert statement

Comment: @AsadAwadia can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: You store rows in a sqlite table not just a list directly. Each item in a list is a row. Each field of the item is the column. So you need to create a table in the db with the schema of the item. Then you use a sqlite client to loop over the list and use an insert into table statement.  I suggest reading the docs or using the link in my profile to reach out for mentoring/tutoring